# Is that necessary to check internet conenction while registering for apns push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, internet-connection

The common way to register for push notification is to add the following code in Appdelegate.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];`

What will happen if there is no internet connection ? Will the application try to register for push notification automatically when the internet connection is back ?

Is that necessary to check internet connection and already registered condition before registering for push notifications like the following

```
if ([wifiConnection wifiConnectivity]){
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"MyAppSpecificGloballyUniqueString"]) {            
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
}
```

Also if we add this to application become active - it will work as expected I hope.

Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no WIFI or network, no register callback will be called, so you do not need to check connection before calling the register method.

As far as I understood it, if you do not have WIFI or cellular connection when calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` but the connection comes back, your delegate method `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` will be called at that moment.

Regarding the second point, you have to register the device token every time your app launches.
Look closely at the Apple guideline on Push Notification, it is really well documented:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

> An application should register every time it launches and give its provider the current token
>
> By requesting the device token and passing it to the provider every time your application launches, you help to ensure that the provider has the current token for the device. If a user restores a backup to a device or computer other than the one that the backup was created for (for example, the user migrates data to a new device or computer), he or she must launch the application at least once for it to receive notifications again. If the user restores backup data to a new device or computer, or reinstalls the operating system, the device token changes. Moreover, never cache a device token and give that to your provider; always get the token from the system whenever you need it. If your application has previously registered, calling registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: results in the operating system passing the device token to the delegate immediately without incurring additional overhead.

You should register the device in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, no need to call it in `didBecomeActive`, the token won't change in that case.